# Differences between .NET network tracing levels

Tags: .net, trace

I'm trying to understand what the different output is for the various .NET Network tracing levels documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx

It states only what the possible values are, and not what the differences are.

> Required  String attribute. Sets the
>   verbosity of the output. Legitimate
>   values are **Critical**, **Error**, **Verbose**,
>   **Warning**, and **Information**.
>
> This attribute must be set on the  element of the 
>   element as shown in the example. An
>   exception is thrown if this attribute
>   is set on the  element.

I would like to basically log *all* events to my log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this to be heirarchical. Meaning Critical logs only critical, Error logs Critical and Error, Verbose logs verbose and critical and Error, etc.

so Informational would log everything.